# headheight has no effect

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I'm trying to reserve more space for the heading, so that the body of the document will start lower on the page. Reading the KOMA-Script user manual, it seems like this should work. Unfortunately, whatever I put for `headheight` has no effect.

```
\documentclass[headheight=10cm]{scrartcl} % setting headheight here has no effect

\KOMAoptions{headheight=10cm} % setting headheight here has no effect either

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}

\ihead{left header}
\chead{centre header}
\ohead{right header}

\ifoot{left footer}
\cfoot{centre footer}
\ofoot{right footer}

Here is some text

\end{document}
```

I'm sure I could hack this by adding some space after the header text, but I'm developing a template, so I don't know in advance what the header text will be.

Comment: I guess you probably either want to change the value of `\topskip` (`\setlength{\topskip}{10cm}`) or maybe add `headinclude` to your document class options, depending on where you want the header relative to the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works using `headinclude=true` in the document options, as you can see:

```
\documentclass[headheight=10cm, headinclude=true]{scrartcl} % setting headheight here has no effect

\KOMAoptions{headheight=10cm} % setting headheight here has no effect either

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}

\ihead{left header}
\chead{centre header}
\ohead{right header}

\ifoot{left footer}
\cfoot{centre footer}
\ofoot{right footer}

Here is some text

\end{document}
```

But I have to admit, I do not understand, why.